How can we get more people into the chat?
I'm fairly new to this site, having just started studying Chinese.
I've been learning French the past 5 years, and French.SE has been an absolutely enormous help to me, beyond words. I've posted a lot of questions there that have become very popular.
But I also make constant and regular use of their chatroom, where I ask the highly specific "localized" questions that aren't really a good fit for the site. It's also a great opportunity to just talk with native speakers and have them correct my mistakes as I go.
I would love if there were a similar situation here, but it seems Chinese.SE's chatroom is nearly always empty. I'm hoping we can enliven it! On French.SE the mods at least are nearly always in the room, even when they're AFK. On Japanese.SE they have two rooms, one for general use and one for pure-Japanese speak (for practicing), and both rooms are in frequent or constant use.
Does anyone have any thoughts for making our chat more than just an empty room?

I think this is generally a pretty quiet site. You can get good answers, but there aren't a ton of questions.
If you want to help increase the traffic, post your own questions and encourage people you meet online or in class to post their questions.
